# Applying pixel shaders to images

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, hlsl

I would like to apply a shader effect to an image in c#/xaml.

I have found this example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.shadereffect(v=vs.95).aspx

Which makes applying pixel shaders to an image pretty trivial. Unfortunately I cannot do the same thing with the windows 8 phone SDK.

Can I do anything this simple? I would like to avoid using DirectX if possible.

Comment: Can you use XNA? Or did you mean XNA when you mentioned DirectX?

Comment: You might want to tag your question with windows phone (or something) so phone dev people will see it more easily.

Answer (score 1):

Check the link below:

[Creating a Lens Application that uses HLSL effects for filters](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Creating_a_Lens_application_that_uses_HLSL_effects_for_filters)

This solution uses SharpDX api (a C# DirectX wrapper).

I've tested recently and it works fine under emulator.

Unfortunally I didn't get the same results when applying outside a Game class. I already published a question here with no responses yet. :-(

Good luck!

Best regards,

Pieter Voloshyn

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot make custom ShaderEffects in Windows Phone 7 or 8. See also: [WP7 - HLSL effects from WPF/Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164812/wp7-hlsl-effects-from-wpf-silverlight)

Also it would appear that XNA is a no-go: 
[Windows Phone custom shaders error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907777/windows-phone-custom-shaders-error)
I don't think XNA has had any feature additions from WP7 to WP8, either.

You might be able to get away with doing what you need in Direct3D: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714072(v=vs.105).aspx)

Good luck!

Comment: FWIW custom shaders are available to native WP8 apps ... and MonoGame apps.

Comment: @lzcd can you provide a link or cite?  I believe that you must be thinking of DirectX shaders.  As far as I know WP8 still does not support custom effects on Framework elements.